# Microsoft Azure Backup Server failing with error 182

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I am tring to install Microsoft Azure Backup Server but it's failing with the following error

> Report configuration failed.
>
> Verify that SQL Server Reporting Services is installed properly and
>   that it is running.
>
> ID: 812

This is what I find in the log

> [2018-04-25 12:09:41 PM] * Exception : =>
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Reporting.ReportingService2005.ListSecureMethods()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.CheckSslInstallation()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.ConnectToReportServerUrl(String
>   RSUrl, Boolean throwExcecption) at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.ConstructReportServerUrl(String
>   sqlServerName, String sqlInstanceName) at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.GetReportServerUrl(String
>   sqlServerName, String sqlInstanceName) at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.CreateReportProxyObject(String
>   sqlServerName, String sqlInstanceName) at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.CreateReportRootFolder(String
>   serverName, String instanceName, Boolean recreate) at
>   Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Library.Reporting.Reporter.InstallReports(Boolean
>   calledFromSetup, String sourceFolderPath, String sqlServerName, String
>   sqlInstanceName, String dbConnectionString)

I have a configured certificate for the Reporting service and I tried deleting the encryption keys but still failed

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that that the SQL Server Reporting Services is installed properly and that it is running and also make sure the appropriate ports (443) are open on the system. You may consider restarting the system and re-trying the operation.

Reference:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3041338/data-protection-manager-error-codes